# Is it possible to determine the date a photo (received via text message) was taken?

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

Is it possible to download a photo received in a text message and determine the date that the photo was taken? I have an iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Cameras usually append EXIF information to photos they take. You may use EXIF Viewer(on Mac) or other softwares to view if there is EXIF.

Comment: And if the photo does not have EXIF data embedded into it, then the answer is no, there is no way to determine the date the photo was taken.

Comment: If there is no EXIF data, try asking the person who took it. Not too hard.